# How to recover the Windows 7 partition in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows-7, boot-failure, data-recovery, boot-partition

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in my machine, and after trying to mount and unmount a SD card, my Windows 7 "has hidden him self",
When i power on the computer,i can enter the Grub and choose

```
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

but, it says

```
error: no such device: B6606771606736F1.
error: invalid signature.
```

How can I recover my Windows 7?
when i do `sudo fdisk -l` it appearsthis

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xfeff8cfd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   523655167   261826560    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       523655168  1359239167   417792000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1359241214  1465147391    52953089    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1359241216  1448818687    44788736   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1448820736  1465147391     8163328   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 24.0 GB, 24015495168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2919 cylinders, total 46905264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x74f02dea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    46901247    23449600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Help please...

Comment: try `boot-repair` tool.

Comment: can you post output of this command: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`?